# Event listeners and transitions JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, dom-events

I tried to use an event listener (click) in order to change the opacity of several elements with transition that the properties toggle every click. I don't know why my code isn't working and can't find my mistake, so I need help.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector(".hamburger").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const con = document.querySelector(".con");
    const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
    if (!con.classList.contains("js")) {
      con.classList.toggle("con-js");
      //forEach link (in const links) toggle the "link-toggle" class
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.con-js {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.con ul li a {
  opacity: 0;
  /*transition for the opacity: opacity .8s 1s*/
}

.link-toggle {
  opacity: 1;
  /*transition for the opacity: opacity .3s 0s;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger" ">
  <!--Hamburger Content-->
</div>
<div class="con ">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html " class="nav-link ">A</a></li>
     <li><a href="menu.html " class="nav-link ">B</a></li>
     <li><a href="# " class="nav-link ">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `if (!con.classList.contains("js"))`
If `con` already contains a class `con-js`, so the code inside `if` block will not run.

Comment: Then what is the solution?

Comment: Can you try to remove the if condition, and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the specificity of CSS selectors.

Given the selector `.con ul li a`, in order to be able to apply `opacity: 1`, you should change the selector `.link-toggle` to `.con ul li a.link-toggle`.

Otherwise, `opacity: 0;` will be more specific and used instead of `opacity: 1;`.

```css
.con ul li a.link-toggle {
  opacity: 1;
  /*transition for the opacity: opacity .3s 0s;*/
}
```

EDIT: In order to toggle the class, `querySelectorAll` will do the trick:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector(".hamburger").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const con = document.querySelector(".con");
    
    if (!con.classList.contains("js")) {
      con.classList.toggle("con-js");
      
      const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
      
      for(const link of links){
        link.classList.toggle("link-toggle");
      } 
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: This is the code that I wrote:
`window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector(".hamburger").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const con = document.querySelector(".con");
    const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
    if (! con.classList.contains("js")) {
      con.classList.toggle("con-js");

      for(const link of links){
        link.classList.toggle("link-toggle");
      }
    }
  })
})`
**It didn't work :(**

Comment: Help Pleassssse?

Comment: @mattanelhiham Please have a look at the JSFiddle I wrote: https://jsfiddle.net/fvbs1p2m/1/ . It should have the answer

Comment: WOW you are an amazing man!!! Thank you for taking your time and help me. It helped me with all of my projects, and in future ones. You don't know how much I appreciate it. Thanks again, genius :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use querySelectorAll instead of just querySelector which will only select the first matching element it comes across.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Hope it Helps! :)

Comment: It did help, but now how can I toggle the "link-toggle" class for each link (in const links)?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you put the class **"nav2-link-con-js"**.

You do not have such a class in css and here **(! сon.classList.contains ("js"))** you are looking for just the class "js".

You need to fix the class **"nav2-link-con-js"**.

Here is how I would do it:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector(".hamburger").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const con = document.querySelector(".con");
    
  con.classList.toggle("nav2-link-con", con.classList.contains("js"));
  con.classList.toggle("js", !con.classList.contains("js"));   
  }) 
})
```

Comment: What? In which line did you see it?